# How do I return error information (as an error!) from ajax action?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I wrote a simple filter attribute implementing IExceptionFilter interface that only handles exception if they occur in ajax actions. There are many examples on the web. Pick any of them.
However, I added a single line:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
```

This due to the fact that any exception filter catch is an error indeed, and I want it to be reported as such. Secondly, I just do not want to wrap any ajax responses in some kind of { success: success, data: data } object.

Now to the problem: on my dev machine everything works flawlessly: if an exception occurs, client get json describing the problem; if not -- returned data is whatever caller is expected it to be. Both for local (who is viewing the site from the same machine) and remote clients.
But when I deploy application on another server, errors only returned in json for local clients, for everyone else - it's standard error html page. **Why is that?** `<customErrors />` mode attribute is set to `RemoteOnly` on both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I solved it:

I enabled Failed Requests Tracing feature on the second machine. Then I run the same request that ought to return error information in json locally and from a remote machine. This gave me two log files. I compared them and found out that it's got something to do with

```
263.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="CustomErrorModule", Notification="SEND_RESPONSE", fIsPostNotification="false" 09:05:49.998 
264.  GENERAL_NOT_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR Reason="EXISTINGRESPONSE_AUTO" 
265.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="CustomErrorModule", Notification="SEND_RESPONSE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE"
```

This how I came to:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

After that I also analyzed machine.config on both machines. Found nothing on this matter. That means I still don't know why it behaved differently in the first place.

Any thoughts?